# .htaccess redirect with argument

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I tried out several redirects but none worked for my needs. Could you please help me to figure out this one? I know, it has been answered many times but I can not get it to work. Thanks.

I need to redirect [from](http://example.com/demo/details?acronym=some-string) [to](http://example.com/demo/some-string)

Examples:

```
 /demo/details?acronym=text15
```

to

```
 /demo/text15
```

or

```
 /demo/details?acronym=text-c15
```

to

```
 /demo/text-c15
```

The correct redirect was:

```
#redirect from  "demo/details\?acronym=some-string" to "/demo/some-string"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /details\?acronym=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /demo/%1? [NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^demo/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /demo/details?acronym=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and the most important part here is that you should call the formatted link not the original link 
e.g. /demo/text15

thats all folks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in your .htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on

#redirect from  "demo/details/acronym\?text=foo" to "/demo/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /details/acronym\?text=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /demo/%1? [NC,L,R]

#skip the rule if the request is for dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #skip the rule if the request is for file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 #rewrite any other request  to "/demo/details?acronym=" 
 RewriteRule ^(?:demo/)?([^/]+)/?$ /demo/details/acronym?text=$1 [NC,L]
```